# Android Studio Kotlin - invisible forms

Tags: android, forms, kotlin

I'm trying to add forms to my app but despite writing further, they are visible in the application.

[image]

How to properly add forms to the application?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you added an XML view to a compose app (both are a way of creating and handling UI, but using them both at once is a... bit of a strange idea ?)

you could do something like:

```kotlin
AndroidView(
  factory = { context ->
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null, false)
    val textView = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.yourId)

    // do whatever you want...
    view // return the view
  },
  update = { view ->
    // Update the view
  }
)
```

in your MainActivity2.kt